# Plotting Arrow when Price Passes Indicator Line

Tags: pine-script

Below is a free public domain code by Linear Regression Trend Channel by midtownsk8rguy

I want to add down arrow plot when price closes below the top line and an up arrow when price closes above the lower line.

```
// Linear Regression Trend Channel by midtownsk8rguy
// https://www.tradingview.com/script/CD7yUWRV-Linear-Regression-Trend-Channel/
//@version=4
study("Linear Regression Trend Channel", "LRTC", true)

drawLine(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, ExtendType, Color, LineStyle) => var line Line = na, Line := line.new(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, xloc.bar_index, ExtendType, Color, LineStyle, 2), line.delete(Line[1]) // Basic Line Drawing Function on one Line
rsdcr2(PeriodMinusOne, Deviations, Estimate) => // Function Calculates Regression, Slope, Deviation, Correlation, and R2
    var period = PeriodMinusOne + 1, var devDenominator = Estimate=="Unbiased" ? PeriodMinusOne : period, Ex = 0.0, Ex2 = 0.0, Exy = 0.0, Ey = 0.0, for i=0 to PeriodMinusOne
        closeI = nz(close[i]), Ex := Ex + i, Ex2 := Ex2 + i * i, Exy := Exy + closeI * i, Ey := Ey + closeI
    ExEx = Ex * Ex, slope = Ex2==ExEx ? 0.0 : (period * Exy - Ex * Ey) / (period * Ex2 - ExEx), linearRegression = (Ey - slope * Ex) / period, intercept = linearRegression + bar_index * slope, deviation = 0.0, for i=0 to PeriodMinusOne
        deviation := deviation + pow(nz(close[i]) - (intercept - bar_index[i] * slope), 2.0)
    deviation := Deviations * sqrt(deviation / devDenominator), correlate = correlation(close, bar_index, period), r2 = pow(correlate, 2.0), [linearRegression, slope, deviation, correlate, r2]
periodTrend    = input(        100,  "Trend Period", input.integer,  minval=  4)
deviationsAmnt = input(       2.0, " Deviation(s)", input.float  ,  minval=0.1, step=0.1)
estimatorType  = input("Unbiased",    " Estimator", input.string , options=["Biased","Unbiased"])
var extendType = input(   "Right", "Extend Method", input.string , options=[ "Right","Segment" ])=="Right" ? extend.right : extend.none
periodMinusOne = periodTrend - 1
[linReg, slope, deviation, correlate, r2] = rsdcr2(periodMinusOne, deviationsAmnt, estimatorType)
endPointBar = bar_index - periodTrend + 1, endPointY = linReg + slope * periodMinusOne
drawLine(endPointBar, endPointY + deviation, bar_index, linReg + deviation, extendType, #FF0000ff, line.style_solid )
drawLine(endPointBar, endPointY            , bar_index, linReg            , extendType, #CCCC00ff, line.style_dotted)
drawLine(endPointBar, endPointY - deviation, bar_index, linReg - deviation, extendType, #00FF00ff, line.style_solid )
var label Label = na, Label := label.new(max(0, endPointBar), endPointY, text=tostring(correlate, "#.####"), color=0.0>correlate ? #AA000080 : #00AA0080, textcolor=#FFFFFFff, style=label.style_label_right, tooltip="Correlation: " + tostring(correlate) + "\n            R2: " + tostring(r2)), label.delete(Label[1]) // Precise Correlation/R2 Label

//my added code (that is not correct)
atest = linReg + deviation
btest = linReg - deviation

BullUp = crossover(close, btest)
BearDown = crossunder(close, btest)

plotarrow(BullUp ? 1 : BearDown ? -1 : 0, title="TEST ", transp=0, colorup=color.green, colordown=color.red, transp=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the lines are being constantly redrawn in the past, so a crossover detected on a bar 20 bars from the end of the chart may no longer be true by the time the lines are redrawn on the chart's last bar.

You can use replay mode to visualize how the lines are redrawn.